# Unable to install django-crispy-forms via pip

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I tried to install django-crispy-forms inside a virtual environment, but what I am getting is this.

Collecting django-crispy-forms
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-crispy-forms (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for django-crispy-forms

I used the following commands:
pip install --upgrade django-crispy-forms
pip install django-crispy-forms

Can anyone help me in finding the issue!
Thanks

Comment: strange. try adding `--verbose` option when running `pip install django-crispy-forms` and copy the output here.

Comment: what is your python version

Answer (score 1):

you can install with using repo URL:

```
pip install -e git+git://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms.git#egg=django-crispy-forms
```

and then add in the installed app in the setting:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'crispy_forms',
)
```

You can refer to this link [here](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-django-crispy-forms)

Comment: but that's the unstable version, what if OP wants the latest stable version?

Comment: you can remove @dev and then install the stable version

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a mac, you can try reinstalling your ssl certificates

```
brew reinstall ca-certificates openssl
```

or upgrading your ssl/system certificate

`pip install --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org --user pip-system-certs'`